# how can I use OpenLayers2 Image layers as base layer?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have created one code to display an image layer on my map using OpenLayers, I am using following code:

```
tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "layername", "domainname/geoserver/workspace/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'layername',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    tiled: true,
                    transparent: "true",
                    tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    yx : {'EPSG:900913' : true}
                } 
            );
            map.addLayer(tiled);
```

My complete code is:

```
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('mapdiv');
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var zoom = 15;
    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(151.1522771, -33.7288868).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")), zoom);
    tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layername", "url", {
            LAYERS : 'layername',
            STYLES : '',
            format : 'image/png',
            tiled : true,
            transparent : "true",
            tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
        }, {
            buffer : 0,
            displayOutsideMaxExtent : true,
            isBaseLayer : true,
            yx : {
                'EPSG:900913' : true
            }
        });
    map.addLayer(tiled);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked it but after that the zoom in and out function is not working with image . I mean that image layer is not changing as per the zoom level, that is showing static size.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are setting `isBaseLayer: false`; This will make the layer an overlay layer.

If you want it as a base layer, then you just need to set it to true, i.e. `isBaseLayer: true`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

I have checked it but after that the zoom in and out function is not working with image .

I mean that image layer is not changing as per the zoom level, that is showing static size.

Comment: @user34591: Then that means that you have not initialised the map properly.

Comment: function init() {map = new OpenLayers.Map('mapdiv');var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();var zoom= 15; map.addLayer(mapnik);map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(151.1522771,-33.7288868).transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")),zoom);
tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layername", "url",{LAYERS: 'layername',STYLES: '',format: 'image/png',tiled: true, transparent: "true",tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom},{buffer: 0,displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,isBaseLayer: true,yx : {'EPSG:900913' : true}} );
map.addLayer(tiled);}

Comment: above is my full code. when I change isBaseLayer: true, as true the image layer is not showing on the map, and its working on false